# How to compare values with multiple values from another table in SQL using IN and LIKE operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of values in one table:

```
GenericUserNames
test
temp
trainee
123
```

Those values need to be compared to the fields `UserID` and `UserName` in this table:

```
UserID, UserName
test123, test 123
GriffinPeter, Peter Griffin
traineeone, trainee one
```

If one of them contains part of one of the values, the `EvalCheck` needs to be set to 1, otherwise to 0.

```
UserID, UserName, EvalCheck
test123, test 123, 1
GriffinPeter, Peter Griffin, 0
traineeone, trainee one, 1
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Select A.GenericUserNames
  B.UserID,
  B.UserName
  (Case
  When B.UserName Or B.UderID Like '%' + In (Select A.GenericUserNames From A) + '%'
  Else 0
  End
  ) As EvalCheck
From  A, B
```

Please note, that I need to compare all columns for one user/line to all values of the generic user names.

Comment: If username is always `LastName` + `FirstName` then left join on `FirstName` in `GenericUserName` and `LastName' in `GenericUserName`; if there is a match then ...

Comment: Correct, ```UserName ```is always ```First- and LastName```. I have changed my question, please have a look.

Comment: What if multiple rows match?

Comment: Which rows do you mean? Potentially every row/record in the user table can contain a match and needs to be marked.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LEFT JOIN` :

```
select distinct t2.UserName, t2.FirstName, t2.LastName,
       (case when t1.GenericUsernames is null then 0 else 1 end) as EvalCheck
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on (t2.UserName like '%' +  t1.GenericUsernames + '%' or
         t2.userid like '%' + t1.GenericUserNames + '%'
        );
```

Note : Use standard explicit *JOIN* syntax instead of comma syntax.

For instance, you are doing a *CROSS* join which is not sufficient for what you are looking.

*LIKE* will be NON-Sargable that means if second table user name has index then query optimized will never use that index to help you to get faster result.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because I need to compare ```UserID``` and ```UserName``` to the complete list of generic users. I have edited my question, so you can better understand it.

Comment: @goatw. . . First, don't change the question between the time that being asked & someone provided the answer. You can add one more check with userid. Check edited.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I don't see why I should use a ```distinct```? Also it still doesn't work, it doesn't set the correct ```EvalCheck```.

Answer (score 2):

Use `exists`:

```
select t2.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table1 t1
                          where t2.userid like '%' + t1.GenericUserNames + '%' or
                                t2.username like '%' + t1.GenericUserNames + '%'
                         )
             then 1 else 0
       end) as EvalCheck
from table2 t2
```

Comment: I have a matching user name in my list, but it still sets ```EvalCheck```to 0. The result of the query needs to include all records form the user table and set the ```EvalCheck```to 1 in every record line where there is a matching generic user name from the first table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t2.UserName, t2.FirstName, t2.LastName,
       (case when t1.GenericUsernames is null then 0 else 1 end) as EvalCheck
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.UserName =  t1.GenericUsernames
     or t2.FirstName=  t1.GenericUsernames
     or t2.LastName=  t1.GenericUsernames
```

Comment: I have changed the question, to better understand what I need. I do not need to look for values with ```NULL```.